# Newly created directories inherit group permissions from parent

Tags: linux, permissions

I create a directory B inside A.

Their permissions :

```
drwxrwsr-x A

drwxr-sr-x B
```

I want B to inherit group write permission from A. How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use POSIX ACLs – set a "default" ACL of `group::rwx` on the directory:

```
setfacl -m d:g::rwx A
```